# How to work with change detection strategy on-push in angular for array

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I'm trying to study how change detection work. having array(children) in parent component and in children using change detection `OnPush`. Trying to change the array by splice or push is still affecting the child component template. How come this works, even though the reference of the `@Input` does not change?

my parent component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  children = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

  emit(j) {
    this.children.splice(j, 1);
  }
}
```

parent html

```
<div>
   <app-multi [input]="children" (output)="emit($event)"></app-multi>
</div>
```

my child component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-multi',
  templateUrl: './multi.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multi.component.css'],
  changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MultiComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges,DoCheck,AfterViewInit{

  @Input('input') ele = [];

  data = [];

  @Output('output') outputEmi = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.ele;
  }

  clicks(value){
    this.outputEmi.emit(value);
  }

}
```

child html

```
{{name.name}}
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let head of data; let i = index;">
                <span>{{head}}</span>
                <button class="delete" (click)="clicks(i)">x</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my understanding, your question is that you are wondering why change detection works, even though the reference of the `@Input` doesn't change?

With the change detection strategy set to `OnPush`, the child component checks its template bindings only for a couple reasons:

- A primitive or reference of an `@Input()` value has changed
- A binded event has happened, which was declared inside the template (like (click))
- The child component emits through `@Output`

In your case the second and last point happened, because of this the `*ngFor` inside your child template runs again, and realizes there is an extra addition to the array from the input.

Bottom line, so even though the reference of the array stays the same, and the `@Input()` does not change reference wise, there is still a change detection triggered, because the child component receives a binded `(click)` and emits an `@Output`.

If you were to update your code, and not use the `@Output()`, the change detection will still work, because an event was binded to the template:

```
clicks(value){
  this.input.splice(value, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro this helps me lot's can you please explain me about use of markForCheck

Comment: Change detection in angular is done from the root to the bottom. This means that if a parent component has `OnPush`, the child component will also behave as `OnPush`, regardless of its setting. Imagine all the components are `OnPush`. If you call `markForCheck` from a child, it will bubble up to the root, marking -all- ancestors as 'dirty', which means in the next `tick()` (change detection), the components will get updated. (not the children of the child though). This is a bit of the opposite of `detectChanges`, because that will go from child to children and only update the dirty ones.

Answer (score 0):

in order to trigger change detection, when it's OnPush you have to change the reference, so if you make `splice` it will not change reference it will just update the existing array, so I encourage you to do `filter` method instead of `splice`, but if you have to use splice than remember to renew the reference like this

```
this.children.splice(i,j);
this.children = [...this.children]
```